# Javascript: Automatically create a popup that downloads a .zip File

Tags: javascript, file, download, popup

I have a download page on my website, and now I want to automatically 'present' my .zip file to a user when he gets on the page.

An example of what I mean:
http://www.chip.de/downloads/c1_downloads_hs_getfile_v1_16103932.html?t=1303674103&v=3600&s=1027a44b945de67a0da2ed759678a800

(In Firefox, the site above will automatically open a save dialog for Firefox) = THis is exactly what I want!

Comment: fenster = window.open(zip, "Download", "width=600,height=400,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes");

Comment: You can't do this using JavaScript, you'll need to send appropriate headers from the server to the client.

Answer (score 1):

You could try running this redirect when the page loads:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.mydownload.com/download.zip';
}
</script>
```

Note: This uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: Will this keep the user at the page after downloading?

Comment: Yes it should. The browser will detect the content type of the URL as being an attachment, and rather than 'present' the page it should trigger the download - keeping the user on the original page.

Comment: @Hans: If your webserver serves ZIP files with `Content-Disposition: attachment` (sane ones will), and the client browser is sane, then yes.

Comment: @James: I don't see why the jQuery is needed here. You don't even need to wait for the DOM to load (though it may be preferable in order not to interrupt that process); still, you don't need jQuery to do that.

Comment: Very true, you don't need jQuery, I just don't leave home without it.

Comment: @Tomalak: because every JS related question on SO requires an answer with jQuery even if it's completely irrelevant ;) @James: Please don't tell me if the above code was all you needed JS for you would still include jQuery in the code :P +1 for the correct answer tho.

Comment: Missing end quote in first line.